# Automatically tag photo locations

Tags: iphone, photos, geolocation, gps

Quite often I have a situation when photos are taken both from iPhone (which would record GPS coordinates) and at the same place/time with DSLR which will not add any location information.

Is there way (tool) to analyze Photos library and mark photos from DSLR with location information using photos from iPhone taken at the same time?